# How can you combine small parquet files using Python on a single computer?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a 24GB CSV file (~26 cols) that I want to convert to Parquet format. From online research, I've learned that, for the best performance, the recommended Parquet file size is between 128MB and 1GB when querying with Amazon Athena.

The following code efficiently converts the CSV to several hundred 6-13MB Parquet files in parallel:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

dd.read_csv('input_24GB.csv', dtype=object).to_parquet('output_folder')
```

In order to control the output size, I used the `blocksize` parameter in `dd.read_csv()`:

```
dd.read_csv('input_24GB.csv', dtype=object, blocksize=1e9).to_parquet('output_folder')
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to accurately predict what the output Parquet file size will be for a specific blocksize. Then I tried to see if I can combine all of the several hundred 6-13MB Parquet files into larger Parquet files so they are at least 128MB. The only solution that I came up with works serially.

Is there a better and faster way to do this entire task with limited compute/memory resources on a laptop?

Answer (score 2):

`blocksize` is only going to control the size of the input data, there's no way to directly control the size of the parquet files you're writing. However, you can look at the number of partitions and the current file sizes to get a decent estimate of the number of partitions you should use to get the file sizes you want. For example, if you're currently getting 200 partitions you could first repartition your dataframe down to 10 before writing the parquet files:

```py
dd.read_csv('input_24GB.csv', dtype=object, blocksize=1e9)
.repartition(npartitions=10)
.to_parquet('output_folder')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the **partition_size** keyword:

```
df = dd.read_csv('input_24GB.csv', dtype=object)
df = df.repartition(partition_size='1GB')
df.to_parquet('output_folder')
```

Comment: One thing to note is that `partition_size` sets the size of each partition in memory, it doesn't directly determine the size of the Parquet files on disk. Parquet is also a compressed format, which makes it difficult to predict the file size in advance.